# calling an external program in matlab in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, file-io, ubuntu-12.04, external

I have installed Matlab 2014 in Ubuntu. My problem:
I build several input files for another program, Quantum Espresso, in Matlab. Now I should pass these files to Quantum Espresso using matlab command line. Now I know I can do this using Linux Terminal, but my way of solving my problem has reached the point that my only option is 'calling Quantum Espresso from matlab'. One single call is actually easy:

```
!  installation/folder/espresso-5.3.0/bin/pw.x <  inputfile > outputfile
```

The problem is I have several input files named like 1name.in 1name.in ... . So this repeated calls should be done in a loop. But how?

I have tried:
the shell script for looping though the files. I added that extra '!' to each line of the script but it doesn't work. 
I also tried to write a loop like this :

```
for i = 1:N

prefix = int2str(i);
fuloutname = [prefix 'name' '.' 'out'];
fulinname  = [prefix 'name' '.' 'in'];
!  adress/espresso-5.3.0/bin/pw.x <  fulinname > fuloutname ;

end
```

In which 'N' in number of my input files. Clearly running this means you are passing a file nemaed 'fulinname' not 1name.in and will result in an output file named 'fuloutname'

I also tried to do it as you normally load various files in a loop but it also did not work

Please help me.

Comment: You should use the `unix` function, `mycommand = 'mycall'` and `unix(mycommand)`

Comment: @obchardon Should I use it like : `command1 = 'for value in $1*.in'` ... and then `unix(command1)`? This results in error:`/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: moved it up from the answer - @fb.researcher - try in matlab `!` plus the string. I really believe @obchardon answered correctly to the question.

Comment: @fb.researcher - so also with it `!` doesn't work? Then I would suggest to make it a different question and for this accept obchardons answer. My guess is there is some issue with how the command is formed as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `unix` function:

```
for i = 1:N

prefix = int2str(i);
fuloutname = [prefix 'name' '.' 'out'];
fulinname  = [prefix 'name' '.' 'in'];
mycommand  = ['adress/espresso-5.3.0/bin/pw.x <  ',fulinname,' > ',fuloutname];
unix(mycommand);
%system(mycommand); %will give you the same, result and this function is cross-platform

end
```

Comment: but I think the `system` command would be the equivalent of the `!`. (it also works on win)

Comment: `unix` will work for unix machine, `dos` for windows machine and `system` for both machines. So yeah it will give the exact same output.

Comment: @obchardon The result is `STOP 1` when it reaches the line `unix(mycommand);`

Comment: @obchardon - yes - my point being that although the asker is on ubuntu so `unix` is working - he might be interested for his program to be cross platform - the same way `!` is cross platform what he originally tried.

Comment: @fb.researcher - sounds your command line is faulty - could the the content of `mycommand` and paste it into terminal?

Comment: @bdecaf  It works perfectly in my terminal.The program executes

Comment: @bdecaf Still doesn not work in MATLAB, How can I find the problem?

Comment: have you check if the path is not the problem ? It's possible that your consol and the `unix` function have not the same default folder.

Comment: @obchardon   My script containing the `unix` command, and my input files are in the same folder. I was specifically careful with this